# Why didn't the Chitauri use jump point in Avengers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, captain-marvel

After watching *Captain Marvel*, one thing is bugging me very much. In the movie Ronan and his fleet used jump points for getting very close to earth and launch an attack.

So why didn't the Chitauri use the same technique in *Avengers*? I mean Loki gained the Tesseract as soon as the movie started. So why did Loki just go through all that trouble of building a portal and giving the Avengers the time to assemble and launch a counter attack? As soon as Loki gained the tesseract, the Chitauri could've just used jump point to take over the earth before any defence could be made.

Comment: Out of universe: because they weren't a thing yet.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The events of Captain Marvel happened prior to the events of Avengers. So I think they were definitely a thing in Avengers.

Comment: @Nazgul In-universe, yes. Out-of-universe, The Avengers came first, so what he means is that the *writers* hadn't come up with the idea of jump points yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There could be many plausible reasons for this the writers could come up with.  Here is one that I have thought of.

Although its not stated in the course of the movie itself, Thanos is in control of the Chitauri, and his primary purpose is to gain the Tesseract and the infinity stone that is contained within it.

The agreement that Thanos has with Loki is to obtain the Tesseract, and in return he will provide an army to conquer the Earth and install Loki as its ruler.

The plan may have stated that if Loki can gain control of the Tesseract, he can prove that by opening a portal between the Earth and the Chitauri.  Then and only then will Thanos allow the attack to proceed.

Comment: Although your answer is convincing, there still remains some confusion. How can it be possible that the person Thanos sent to retrive the tesseract didn't give him a universal communicator of some sort ( the kind of communicator Captain Marvel uses in her movie).

Comment: Loki was able to communicate with The Other ... almost appearing in person with him. He was holding the scepter while doing this so it may have been involved in this (the mindstone allowing a telepathic conversation?).

Comment: Loki is known to be a bit of a trickster .... communicating "send the army" may not have been trusted without the proof of opening a portal using the space stone.

Comment: Worth considering also that Thanos wouldn't know when to start moving the Chitauri until after Loki has the portal - we have seen in other films that it can take a number of jump gates to get somewhere (see GoTG2).  With the Space Stone, the Chitauri don't need to be moved from wherever they are to be able to immediately begin the attack